# open a page in new tab and copy the page text property on_completed

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have done this before with vb.net using the browser control, on_completed i can copy the text not html on the page but i do not know how to do it since i am already on a browser and do not know if it is possible to open a mini browser, and copy the text on the page. I need to open a page with a url and confirm the result from the API and then proceed on my page